# Today & Tomorrow Summaries re-add to Notifications on reboot.

Tags: macos, icloud, notifications

Every time I reboot my computer, Today Summary and Tomorrow Summary re-add themselves to my Notification Center. I remove them (click Edit, click the red block button, click Done), and they only stay removed until next reboot.

I'm the only user on my machine. My account is admin. I sync with iCloud, but I don't use these widgets in iOS either, and they don't re-appear there ever.

Is there perhaps a pref file I should trash, or a cache I should reset?

MacBook Pro
macOS 10.12.5 Sierra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s possible your Notification Center preference file is corrupted.

Open **Finder**, then press <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd>. In the popup textbox, type in `~/Library/Preferences`.

Locate `com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist` and delete it. Restart your system and see if the issue persists. If it does, you can pull the file back out of the Trash and restart one more time.